# Pandas - Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'player_id':[86508, 86509, 86508,86509 ], 
                    'match_id': [243061,243061, 243062, 243062], 
                    'line_up':[1,1,1,1]})
```

and:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'player_id':[86508, 86509, 86508, 86509 ], 
                    'match_id': [243061,243061, 243062, 243062]})
```

---

And I need to bring 'line_up' values from `df1` to `df2`, base on 'player_id'. I have tried to use `map()`:

```
df2['line_up'] = df2['player_id'].map(df1.set_index('player_id')['line_up'])
```

But this throws me the error:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

---

Is there any other simple workaround this limitation?

Player ids will repeated many many times, and duplicates cannot be dropped, because each round (match_id) matters.

Comment: remove duplicates maybe : ``df2.player_id.map(df1.set_index("player_id").line_up.drop_duplicates())`` ?

Comment: can't be done, unfortunately.

Comment: you cant drop duplicates? what do you mean by cant be done?

Comment: I did not get what you mean by removing duplicates. I thought you meant remove rows where there is a player_id dup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me;

```
df2['line_up'] = df2['player_id'].map(dict(zip(df1['player_id'],df1['line_up'])))
```

I however think using your approach as follows would.

```
df2['line_up'] = df2['player_id'].map(df1.set_index('player_id')['line_up'].to_dict())
```

Comment: the dict part will remove duplicates, since in a dictionary, you can only have unique keys

Answer (score 1):

dfs will join on index (not row) by assignment.  You can do something like this:

```
df2 = df2.set_index("player_id")
df2["line_id"] = df1.set_index("player_id")["line_up"]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

output:

```
   player_id  match_id  line_vals
0      86508    243061          1
1      86509    243061          1
2      86508    243062          1
3      86509    243062          1
```